# display flex and all its compatibilities in html. Classes vs Id and labels

Tags: html, css

Developing a website and trying to performance and optimice my code, I realiced that the property `display: flex` had more ways to be called depending of the version and the browser.

At the beginning I had everything like the code pasted bellow:

```
section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section > div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section > div > h1{
     display: flex;
     cursor: default;
     align-items: center;
}
```

Then I realiced that I could do the same by calling 2 css. The first one called compatibility.css which contained all the different values for flex properties and the second one with different properties for every tag, like colors, widths, heights, etc.

```
 <section class="justify_center valign_center">
        <div class="flex valign_center flex_direction_column justify_center">
            <h1 class="flex, valign_center></h1>
    .
    .
    .
```

Compatibility.css

```
.flex{
     display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
     display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
     display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
     display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
     display: flex;      
}

    .
    .
    .
```

After I did it, I tried to add responsive design changing some values with media queries but I realiced that for what flex property I wanted to change, I had to add an !important attribute or equal the specify of the HTML css calling.

So what I'm looking for is an advice of how where should I write all these different combinations and if it's convinient to have everything in the CSS instead of HTML classes.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Advice on how to improve your existing, working code is better asked for on CodeReview, a sister site to Stack Overflow. As this is an opinionated question (i.e. "which is better?"), it is off-topic here.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like it might be best to use class names that describe what the elements are and put all the styles you need in your CSS for those classes.

If you would be re-using these same styles a lot and would prefer to use generic helper classes like `flex` and `valign_center` but need different styles for different viewport sizes, you could just add helper classes like `valign_center_sm` `valign_center_md` `valign_center_lg` `valign_center_xl` and `valign_top_sm` etc.

You could then do stuff like this:

```
<div class="valign_stretch valign_top_sm valign_center_lg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.valign_stretch{
   align-items: stretch;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .valign_top_sm{
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .valign_center_lg{
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

This example would stretch it on mobile, top align it >768px and center align it >1200px. You would need to use `max-width` instead of `min-width` on your media queries if you want to do your CSS desktop-first instead of mobile-first.

I can't really be sure which way is better without more information, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: 1. Answering opinionated questions is a good way to attract downvotes from people who disagree with your opinion.  2. Class names like `valign_center` are no more semantic than what the OP is considering using.

Comment: @cimmanon I was just suggesting how he could use breakpoint modifiers to avoid having to use `!important`. I am not suggesting that `valign_center` is more semantic than what he is currently using -- it IS what he is currently using... 

I was suggesting the opposite, actually, that it might be more convenient to use more semantic class names if these helper classes aren't re-used a lot.

Comment: The OP is not asking about whether or not they should be using `!important`.

Comment: @cimmanon It sounded to me like he was asking where he could put the styles to avoid having to use `!important`. I gave him two options.

Comment: Well, after many time studying the case and trying to understand how classes worked (because the problem, mainly was there), I finally decided to, in my css file for that html, group all the selectors separated by colons setting the flex property for that group with all the different compatibilities.